# Alignment of text when column width is changed from GUI in winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, listview

I have developed a winform application. It has a listview with multiple columns having different texts. Initially, I have set the column width = -2 to take the size of longest text in the column.

The issue is that sometime text overshoots the laptop screen and a horizontal scroll bar appeared in the list view.

To fit all the columns in a screen, I manually modified the columns widths using column boundaries in the GUI. When I modify the column width, the column text starts disappearing from right. I want it to disappeared from left.

I have searched goggle a lot but did not find the answer.

Question might look weird or may be I have not explained it properly. Please let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a built-in option, text is always left-aligned.  You'll need to use the DrawSubItem event to get it the way you want.  Use the example code in the MSDN article to get started.

Answer (score -1):

The Listbox columns in Windows Forms are not exactly a high level control, I've used it some times but just for simple lists, It certainly has not a builtin function to make what you want, to obtain it you probably need to subclass the control, create a new class for the item managed in the list and write some code to perform what you need.
I think you can find some hints on how to achieve all this in Charles Petzold book about windows forms where he shows how to measure a string and how to draw directly on your control.